# Mod_rewrite getting 500 server error, ubuntu server

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, ubuntu-server

Hello i have been struggling alot today with my new home server. I have installed newest release of ubuntu server on it. Installed php, apache, mysql and everything seemed to work perfect.

I am trying to set up a website that worked perfectly with XAMPP on my local machine. I have been using this guide to set up mod_rewrite. http://www.solutionsamir.com/20110303140/Operating-Systems/Linux-Unix/How-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-ubuntu-server-for-apache2.html

Here is my HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index.php$
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And here is my 000-default
`
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride all
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

`

Its working somehow, but everytime i post a form, i get 500 internal server error. Any idea whats wrong?

Edit: This is what i get by activating logging.

```
    192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] add path info postfix: /var/www/serverpanel/login -> /var/www/serverpanel/login/
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/serverpanel/login/ -> login/
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] applying pattern '^(.+)/$' to uri 'login/'
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] rewrite 'login/' -> 'index.php'
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/serverpanel/index.php
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/serverpanel/index.php -> /serverpanel/index.php
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] internal redirect with /serverpanel/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f5289230208/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/serverpanel/index.php -> index.php
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f5289230208/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] applying pattern '^(.+)/$' to uri 'index.php'
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:22 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f5289230208/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] pass through /var/www/serverpanel/index.php
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] add path info postfix: /var/www/serverpanel/login -> /var/www/serverpanel/login/
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/serverpanel/login/ -> login/
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] applying pattern '^(.+)/$' to uri 'login/'
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] rewrite 'login/' -> 'index.php'
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/serverpanel/index.php
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/serverpanel/index.php -> /serverpanel/index.php
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f528923b0a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] internal redirect with /serverpanel/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f52892304b8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/serverpanel/index.php -> index.php
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f52892304b8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] applying pattern '^(.+)/$' to uri 'index.php'
192.168.1.110 - - [04/Apr/2012:23:41:52 +0200] [192.168.1.233/sid#7f52893ad1d8][rid#7f52892304b8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] pass through /var/www/serverpanel/index.php
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the two lines   RewriteLog "rewrite.log"  and RewriteLogLevel 3  in your 000-default?  You may find their output helpful.

Comment: Interesting - this suggests the 500 error is coming from the PHP script (and not from the apache config).  I should note I am assuming you've checked ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log and found nothing helpful.  If PHP is causing the problem, you may need to enable error logging at the top of the PHP file.

Comment: Here's my theory: your browser is being redirected from serverpanel/login to serverpanel/login/ by mod_dir *before* mod_rewrite is invoked, and the browser is discarding the POST data.  This causes the index.php file to die unhappily.  You can use wget -d <url> to check for any redirects (or curl -v <url>).

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, with logs. It deserves some attention **`;)`**

As I can see it, you're trying to connect to your local URL `login/`.

Going through your rewrite rules, at the end, it's

```
/var/www/serverpanel/index.php -> /serverpanel/index.php
```

to it's redirected to another URL (not using the actual Php) which is `/serverpanel/index.php`.

So it tries to apply once again the rules, but with `/serverpanel/index.php`.

As you can guess, it will be rewritten to go to `index.php`, thus doing an infinite loop.

Take a close look at your log:

```
(1) [perdir /var/www/serverpanel/] internal redirect with /serverpanel/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

This may be the key to your solution: `perdir /var/www/serverpanel/`

2 questions:

- Is there any `.htaccess` file here?
- If there isn't any `.htaccess`, try to check **all** your Apache conf files, looking for
  a `<Directory "xxx">` directive that concerns `/var/www/serverpanel/`, and you may find where the problem is.

Hope this helps